# How to highlight cell on hover with exceptions

Tags: jquery, cell

I'm trying to highlight a table cell on hover. That's easy enough with jQuery or CSS, but I have a number of small divs within the cell and when these are hovered I want the div only to highlight and NOT the whole cell;

[eg, the following cell...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFAt.png)

So the image shows one table cell with 10 divs; when one of the small rectangle divs are hovered they need to be highlighted, but when any part of the cell excluding the divs is hover then the  itself is highlighted.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes, I've tried all the css and jquery solutions I can think of, but it appears the <td> hover always activates even when hovering the div, as the divs are "above" the <td>. The one thing I have not tried that can think of is absolute positioning and z-index, but I'm hoping to avoid that.
I would have thought this was not an uncommon issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it with jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    var td = $("td");

    // add/remove .hovering for table cells as normal
    td.hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovering");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovering");
    })

    // add/remove .hovering for <div> and do opposite for parent <td>
    $("div").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovering");
        td.removeClass("hovering");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovering").parents("td").addClass("hovering");
    })
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}
div.hovering {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 650px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
td.hovering {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!. Weirdly I had previously tried exactly this solution and could not get the div hover to fire. Cheers